# How to initialize variables to None/Undefined and compare to other variables in Python?

Tags: python

Basically I have some variables that I don't want to preinitialize:

```
originalTime = None
recentTime = None
postTime = None

def DoSomething ( ) :
    if originalTime == None or (postTime - recentTime).seconds > 5 :
        ...
```

I get compile error on the if:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'originalTime' referenced before assignment
```

As you can see, all the variables have different relationship that either has to be set right (time, time + 5, etc) or None at all, but I don't wanna set them to precalculated values when just declaring them to None is easier.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to post more code.  This snippet is fine.  There's not enough information to reproduce or even understand the problem.

Comment: -1; even after being edited, this question is still incomprehensible. The `DoSomething` function doesn't show any assignment to any of the variables (without which no `UnboundLocalError` will occur) and it's unclear what your actual question is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I need to correct Jarret Hardie, and since I don't have enough rep to comment.

The global scope is not an issue.  Python will automatically look up variable names in enclosing scopes.  The only issue is when you want to change the value.  If you simply redefine the variable, Python will create a new local variable, unless you use the global keyword.  So

```
originalTime = None

def doSomething():
  if originalTime:
    print "originalTime is not None and does not evaluate to False"
  else:
    print "originalTime is None or evaluates to False"

def doSomethingElse():
  originalTime = True

def doSomethingCompletelyDifferent()
  global originalTime
  originalTime = True

doSomething()
doSomethingElse()
doSomething()
doSomethingCompletelyDifferent()
doSomething()
```

Should output:

```
originalTime is None or evaluates to False
originalTime is None or evaluates to False
originalTime is not None and does not evaluate to False
```

I second his warning that this is bad design.

Comment: I see that the discussion points the usage of global inside a function is a bad design. But maybe show some example code on the proper design? Show us what you think would be the right way to do things.. I profess that I am not a Python purist, so anything that gets my code to work the way I wanted, I use it. Until I find something better of course.

Answer (score 6):

Your code should have worked, I'm guessing that it's inside a function but originalTime is defined somewhere else.
Also it's a bit better to say `originalTime is None` if that's what you really want or even better, `not originalTime`.

Comment: Just to add to Scott's apposite advice on is None: keep in mind that "not originalTime" will match cases where originalTime is 0 or "" or False, whereas originalTime is None will match only those cases where originalTime is actually "None". Many developers use this difference to delineate variables that have not been specified from those that have no value in the execution context. (ie: def myfunc(somevar=None):    if somevar is None: somevar = 5 # otherwise assume that somevar = 0 is deliberate)

Answer (score 1):

If the `if` statement is inside a function, but the `= None` declarations are at the module-level, then the variables are out of scope inside the function. The simplest fix is to explicitly indicate that the variable identifiers are to be found in the global scope:

```
def doSomething():
    global originalTime
    if originalTime:
        print "originalTime exists and does not evaluate to False"
```

Many folks regard this as poor Python design, btw. If you agree with that assessment, and your architecture permits, you may wish to refactor your function so that it receives external dependencies as function arguments.

Comment: Thanks, for the bad design I agree. If it was pure python, I wouldn't do this, but I am using the python integration of a 3d party app, which is done very badly and buggy, but that's what I have to use.

Comment: -1; this is incorrect or at least highly misleading as written. It's perfectly possible to use variables from an outer scope inside a function, as long as you don't try to assign to them from anywhere within the function body.

Answer (score 1):

==> if initial value is None

```
>>>toto = None

>>>toto = toto if toto is not None else "default Value"

>>>toto

'default value'
```

==> in the case the variable just doesn't exist

```
>>>del toto

>>>toto = toto if locals().get('toto') else "default Value"

>>> toto

'default value'
```

==> same command in case the value is set

```
>>>toto = 1

>>>toto

1

>>>toto = toto if locals().get('toto') else "default Value"

1
```

Answer (score -1):

There's not really any "pretty" way around this.  Just based on the variable names that you've given, my first instinct is to create an object:

```
class SomeTimeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, recentTime=None, originalTime=None, postTime=None):
        self.recentTime = recentTime
        self.originalTime = originalTime
        self.postTime = postTime

time = SomeTimeClass()
if not time.recentTime::
    ...
```

This might work because it sounds like the variables are correlated.  A couple of other options:

Wrap the procedure in a function:

```
def SomeFunc(recentTime=None, originalTime=None, postTime=None):
    if not recentTime:
        ...
```

Use a dict:

```
some_dict = {}

if not some_dict.get('originalTime', None): #return None if key doesn't exist
    ...
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why was this voted down?  Did I get something wrong?

Answer (score -3):

I just tried your code in the shell and I didn't get an error. It should work. Maybe post the entire code?
You can also use try/catch.

Or maybe locals().has_key('originalTime') ?